# How to set IgnoreTrailingSlash on UriTemplate

Tags: vb.net, wcf, rest

I have REST Service written in vb.net and I have the following `<WebGet>`

```
<WebGet(UriTemplate:="Servers", ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedResponse)>
```

So I want to be able to catch requests made to `Servers` & `Servers/` so I can change `UriTemplate:="Servers/"`, but I'd read about `IgnoreTrailingSlash` but I can't figure how I set that on my `<WebGet>`.  I know it needs to be set on the `UriTemplate` but I'm totally stuck on this.

Answer (score 0):

This should help -

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/{key}/")]
```

A good read here -

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2011/05/23/how-to-handle-the-trailing-slash-in-a-wcf-http-service.aspx

Comment: Thanks for that, yes I know that adding the trailing space to the UriTemplate will give the desired affect, but I've found that in doing this I can't read the Authorization Headers (raised here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33894869/how-to-set-and-read-authorization-header-using-vb-net)